# AngularJs submit form and reset $pristine state

Tags: forms, angularjs

Taken this form as example http://plnkr.co/edit/fHEBw6dDdG3IVgnmCLb7?p=preview
How can I put the `$pristine` state of the form to true after the `SAVE DRAFT` button is pressed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call [`$setPristine`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#methods_%24setpristine) on the `form`: http://plnkr.co/edit/wXaFXtuhNH6d4SP2uArm?p=preview

```html
<button ng-click="reset(); form.$setPristine()">RESET</button>
<button ng-click="update(user); form.$setPristine()">SAVE</button>
```

Or you can call the method in your controller (after ensuring that the form exists):

```js
  $scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.master= angular.copy(user);
    if ($scope.form) $scope.form.$setPristine();
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    if ($scope.form) $scope.form.$setPristine();
  };
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mau7uuDfPlzcn418OdWh?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the `reset()` won't clear the email input unless it's valid.
I've tried another approach instead:

```
<button type="reset" ng-click="form.$setPristine()">RESET</button>
<button ng-click="update(user); form.$setPristine()">SAVE</button>
```