# Angularjs 1.4.7 - Clear and set form to pristine state after submission

Tags: angularjs, forms

After submission, my form displays as dirty with a red border and no submission text. I've tried adding various combinations of .$setPristine and/or .$setUntouched to line 34 in app.js with a return of a green border with submission text still in place.

I've read in articles about using $scopes. Not sure if it is required, I'm not familiar with them.

**app.js**

```
* the page hello-world auto-reloads the preview on the right c9 panel */
/* global angular */ /* angular is defined in html document as a src'ed js file. linter says to declare as a global in a comment here */
(function(){
  // variables are declared at the top of the function's scope
  // three default entries to start with
  var entries = [{ 
    title: 'Title1', 
    body: 'This is a test, 1.',
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }, { 
    title: 'Title2', 
    body: 'This is a test, 2.',
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }, { 
    title: 'Title3', 
    body: 'This is a test, 3.',
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }];

  var app = angular.module('blogPosts', []);

  app.controller('EntriesController', function(){ 
    // `this` entry, the current entry for this method, is defaulted to an empty object
    this.entry = {};
    this.entries = entries;

    // method is called when adding an entry
    this.addEntry = function() {
      // does this.entry exist here? good way to find out is with `console.log(this.entry);` or `debugger;`
      this.entry.createdOn = Date.now();
      entries.push(this.entry);
      console.log("entries",entries);
      // reset `this.entry` back to an empty object
      this.entry.$setPristine();
      this.entry = {};
      //this.entry.$setPristine = {};
      //this.entry.$clearForm = {};
    };
  });


})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blogPosts">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /><!-- load Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.min.css" /><!-- load Bootstrap -->
  <script src="angular.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="EntriesController as entryCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="entry in entryCtrl.entries">
      <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3><cite class="clearfix">{{this.entry.createdOn | date}}</cite><br>
      {{entry.body}}
    </div>

      <!--  Entry Form -->
      <form name="entryForm"  
      ng-submit="entryForm.$valid &&entryCtrl.addEntry(entry)" 
      noValidate>

        <!--  Live Preview -->
        <blockquote>
          <h3>{{entryCtrl.entry.title}}</h3><br>
          {{entryCtrl.entry.body}}      
          <cite class="clearfix">{{this.entry.createdOn | date}}</cite>
        </blockquote>

      <!--  Entry Form -->
        <h4>Submit an Entry</h4>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <input type="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" title="Title" ng-model="entryCtrl.entry.title"  required/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write your entry.." title="Entry" ng-model="entryCtrl.entry.body" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit Entry" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: red;
}

.ng-valid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You need the $setPristine on the form element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs submit form and reset $pristine state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490958/angularjs-submit-form-and-reset-pristine-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Reddit /u/mcassagnes

```
app.controller('EntriesController', ['$scope', function($scope){ 
    // ...    
    this.addEntry = function() {
        // ...
        $scope.entryForm.$setPristine();
    };
}]);
```

Works!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this in your this.addEntry is not bound to the lexical this. Basically lost its binding. Best to assign this to a variable in your main controller definition. Something like this to abstract this in controllers. Note you'd have to change the way you'd like to use this syntax. In your view it be EntriesController as vm, and instead of variable just by itself it be vm.variable. Here is a [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) to help solidify what I mean. Hope this helps in your future.

```
  app.controller('EntriesController', function() {
    // `this` entry, the current entry for this method, is defaulted to an empty object
    var vm = this;
    vm.entry = {};
    vm.entries = entries;

    // method is called when adding an entry
    vm.addEntry = function() {
      // does this.entry exist here? good way to find out is with `console.log(this.entry);` or `debugger;`
      this.entry.createdOn = Date.now();
      entries.push(this.entry);
      console.log("entries", entries);
      // reset `this.entry` back to an empty object
      vm.entry.$setPristine();
      vm.entry = {};
      //this.entry.$setPristine = {};
      //this.entry.$clearForm = {};
    };
  });
```